# Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth not working: 100% cpu usage

Tags: bluetooth, cpu

Ever since I updated my laptop to Ubuntu 18.04 my bluetooth has not been working. When I try to open bluetooth in the system settings it takes a while to open and when I turn it on or off it keeps saying "Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers".

I thought to fix this issue later but since I also noticed my battery drains insanely fast I wondered what that could be. Using the "top" or "htop" command in my terminal I saw the cause of this. The process "bluetoothd" is showing 100% CPU usage. I wonder what it's doing because it's unusable.

Now I really want to be able to use bluetooth again and I tried different ways to fix it, namely:

- adding "AutoEnable=true" in /etc/bluetooth/main.cfg
- *sudo apt install bluez*
- *sudo service bluetooth stop/start/restart*
- *systemctl bluetooth stop/start*

Probably some other stuff I can't remember. Anyway to stop my laptop from draining the battery I have to force the "bluetoothd" process to stop. Otherwise my laptop will be dead within one hour...

My bluetoothd version is 5.50, I thought I manually updated that too but I'm not sure.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

**EDIT:** `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3ed Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2134 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT2:** `dmesg | grep -i blue; uname -a; rfkill list`

```
[   25.918370] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   25.918390] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   25.918393] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   25.918395] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   25.918398] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   26.426223] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[   26.474144] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[   26.613246] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   45.410462] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   45.410466] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   45.410472] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Linux HP 4.20.13-042013-generic #201902270533 SMP Wed Feb 27 10:35:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**EDIT3:** `systemctl status bluetooth`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-03-04 16:24:58 CET; 2s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 25143 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─25143 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

mrt 04 16:24:58 HP systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: Starting SDP server
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: avrcp-controller: Protocol not supported (93)
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
mrt 04 16:24:58 HP bluetoothd[25143]: audio-avrcp-target: Protocol not supported (93)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue; uname -a; rfkill list`

Comment: The kernel part is OK, Please add output of `systemctrl status bluetooth`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the feeling that I have a similar issue with my onboard Bluetooth (Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter) but not with an external one....

Comment: @oberfreak Unfortunately not, I haven't tried installing 20.04 either which might fix it, but I'm not sure