# Bluez stuck at high CPU and bluetooth not working

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I am trying to get bluetooth running according to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bluetooth/Einrichtung/.
However, as soon as I install bluez, the process bluetoothd takes very high CPU share and wont stop.
Also, I cannot open blueman...

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

I have Lubuntu 18.04 on a Thinkpad T420 and small basic knowledge in Linux.

Cheers,

Linus

Comment: If you have a nvidia GPU see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073185/after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-to-18-04-systemd-udevd-uses-100-cpu

Comment: hm I dont see how that could help in my case... shall I stop and restart the bluetoothd process? @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Answer (score 0):

Did you get it to work again? Mine still doesn't work and I keep on turning off the bluetooth service after I booted my laptop...

[(my topic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121703/ubuntu-18-04-bluetooth-not-working-100-cpu-usage)

Comment: No, unfortunately not...@Dennis